# Keras ConcatOp : Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train the https://public.roboflow.com/object-detection/self-driving-car/3 dataset with YOLOv8 using Keras (I used the example from [https://keras.io/examples/vision/yolov8/[Keras](https://keras.io/examples/vision/yolov8/%5BKeras) and Yolov8][1](https://keras.io/examples/vision/yolov8/)):

```
"""# Setup"""

import os
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import requests
import zipfile

import keras_cv
from keras_cv import bounding_box
from keras_cv import visualization
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Download dataset.
def download_file(url, save_name):
    if not os.path.exists(save_name):
        print(f"Downloading file")
        file = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        total_size = int(file.headers.get('content-length', 0))
        block_size = 1024
        progress_bar = tqdm(
            total=total_size,
            unit='iB',
            unit_scale=True
        )
        with open(os.path.join(save_name), 'wb') as f:
            for data in file.iter_content(block_size):
                progress_bar.update(len(data))
                f.write(data)
        progress_bar.close()
    else:
        print('File already present')

download_file(
    'https://app.roboflow.com/...',
    'cars.zip'
)

# Unzip the data file
def unzip(zip_file=None):
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file) as z:
            z.extractall("./")
            print("Extracted all")
    except:
        print("Invalid file")

unzip('cars.zip')


"""# Hyperparameters"""

SPLIT_RATIO = 0.2
BATCH_SIZE = 4
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
EPOCH = 5
GLOBAL_CLIPNORM = 10.0

# check if an image is grayscale
def is_grayscale(image_path):
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    if len(img.shape) < 3: return True
    if img.shape[2]  == 1: return True
    b,g,r = img[:,:,0], img[:,:,1], img[:,:,2]
    if (b==g).all() and (b==r).all(): return True
    return False

class_ids = [
    "car",
    "pedestrian",
    "trafficLight-Red",
    "trafficLight-Gree",
    "truck",
    "trafficLight",
    "biker",
    "trafficLight-RedLeft",
    "trafficLight-GreenLeft",
    "trafficLight-Yellow",
    "trafficLight-YellowLeft"
]
class_mapping = dict(zip(range(len(class_ids)), class_ids))

# Path to images and annotations
path_images = "../content/train/"
path_annot = "../content/train/"

# Get all XML file paths in path_annot and sort them
xml_files = sorted(
    [
        os.path.join(path_annot, file_name)
        for file_name in os.listdir(path_annot)
        if file_name.endswith(".xml")
    ]
)

# Get all JPEG image file paths in path_images and sort them
jpg_files = sorted(
    [
        os.path.join(path_images, file_name)
        for file_name in os.listdir(path_images)
        if file_name.endswith(".jpg") and not is_grayscale(os.path.join(path_images,     file_name))
    ]
)

def parse_annotation(xml_file):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    image_name = root.find("filename").text
    image_path = os.path.join(path_images, image_name)

    boxes = []
    classes = []
    for obj in root.iter("object"):
        cls = obj.find("name").text
        classes.append(cls)

        bbox = obj.find("bndbox")
        xmin = float(bbox.find("xmin").text)
        ymin = float(bbox.find("ymin").text)
        xmax = float(bbox.find("xmax").text)
        ymax = float(bbox.find("ymax").text)
        boxes.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])

    class_ids = [
        list(class_mapping.keys())[list(class_mapping.values()).index(cls)]
        for cls in classes
    ]
    return image_path, boxes, class_ids


image_paths = []
bbox = []
classes = []
for xml_file in tqdm(xml_files):
    image_path, boxes, class_ids = parse_annotation(xml_file)
    image_paths.append(image_path)
    bbox.append(boxes)
    classes.append(class_ids)

bbox = tf.ragged.constant(bbox)
classes = tf.ragged.constant(classes)
image_paths = tf.ragged.constant(image_paths)

data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_paths, classes, bbox))

# Determine the number of validation samples
num_val = int(len(xml_files) * SPLIT_RATIO)

# Split the dataset into train and validation sets
val_data = data.take(num_val)
train_data = data.skip(num_val)

def load_image(image_path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    return image


def load_dataset(image_path, classes, bbox):
    # Read Image
    image = load_image(image_path)
    bounding_boxes = {
        "classes": tf.cast(classes, dtype=tf.float32),
        "boxes": bbox,
    }
    return {"images": tf.cast(image, tf.float32), "bounding_boxes": bounding_boxes}

"""# Data Augmentation"""

augmenter = keras.Sequential(
    layers=[
        keras_cv.layers.RandomFlip(mode="horizontal", bounding_box_format="xyxy"),
        keras_cv.layers.RandomShear(
            x_factor=0.2, y_factor=0.2, bounding_box_format="xyxy"
        ),
        keras_cv.layers.JitteredResize(
            target_size=(640, 640), scale_factor=(0.75, 1.3), bounding_box_format="xyxy"
        ),
    ]
)

"""# Creating Training Dataset"""

train_ds = train_data.map(load_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(BATCH_SIZE * 4)
train_ds = train_ds.ragged_batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
train_ds = train_ds.map(augmenter, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

"""# Creating Validation Dataset"""

resizing = keras_cv.layers.JitteredResize(
    target_size=(640, 640),
    scale_factor=(0.75, 1.3),
    bounding_box_format="xyxy",
)

val_ds = val_data.map(load_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.shuffle(BATCH_SIZE * 4)
val_ds = val_ds.ragged_batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
val_ds = val_ds.map(resizing, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)


def dict_to_tuple(inputs):
    return inputs["images"], inputs["bounding_boxes"]


train_ds = train_ds.map(dict_to_tuple, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

val_ds = val_ds.map(dict_to_tuple, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

"""# Creating Model"""

backbone = keras_cv.models.YOLOV8Backbone.from_preset(
    "yolo_v8_s_backbone_coco"  # We will use yolov8 small backbone with coco weights
)

yolo = keras_cv.models.YOLOV8Detector(
    num_classes=len(class_mapping),
    bounding_box_format="xyxy",
    backbone=backbone,
    fpn_depth=1,
)

"""# Compile the Model"""

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
    global_clipnorm=GLOBAL_CLIPNORM,
)

yolo.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer, classification_loss="binary_crossentropy", box_loss="ciou"
)

"""# COCO Metric Callback"""

class EvaluateCOCOMetricsCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, data, save_path):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.metrics = keras_cv.metrics.BoxCOCOMetrics(
            bounding_box_format="xyxy",
            evaluate_freq=1e9,
        )

        self.save_path = save_path
        self.best_map = -1.0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        self.metrics.reset_state()
        for batch in self.data:
            images, y_true = batch[0], batch[1]
            y_pred = self.model.predict(images, verbose=0)
            self.metrics.update_state(y_true, y_pred)

        metrics = self.metrics.result(force=True)
        logs.update(metrics)

        current_map = metrics["MaP"]
        if current_map > self.best_map:
            self.best_map = current_map
            self.model.save(self.save_path)  # Save the model when mAP improves

        return logs

"""# Train the Model"""

yolo.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=3,
    callbacks=[EvaluateCOCOMetricsCallback(val_ds, "model.h5")],
)
```

After 1 Epoch, I get the following error message:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__ConcatV2_N_98_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} ConcatOp : Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal: shape[0] = [4,1,4] vs. shape[1] = [4,3,4] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat

 [Op:EagerPyFunc] name:
```

The thing is, that this example did run successfully with the same dataset. After a few days, it just decided to not run and throw this error message.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Today it run successfully without any errors.